# Get median values from sorted data

Tags: java, median

I have a set of sorted (ascending) data in the format below:

```
| Category | Value | S.D. |
|     A    |  0.1  | 0.1  |
|     A    |  0.2  | 0.05 |
|     A    |  1.3  | 0.08 |
|     B    |  0.1  | 0.01 |
|     B    |  0.2  | 0.08 |
|     B    |  0.6  | 0.9  |
|     B    |  0.7  | 0.01 |
|     B    |  0.9  | 0.05 |
|     B    |  1.1  | 0.6  |
|     C    |  0.5  | 0.3  |
|     C    |  0.9  | 0.04 |
|     C    |  1.0  | 0.14 |
|     C    |  2.1  | 0.1  | etc...
```

There are about 300 rows of this. I have imported this from csv and have sorted as a `List`. For example `data.get(1).getCategory()` results in "A", and `data.get(2).getValue()` results in "0.2" (It is a `String` as I am using a library.)

The data is subject to change. I need to calculate a median value for each category, and print each median value with it's category name. Where there are an even number of entries, the middle value with the smallest S.D. should be used. For example, using the above data:

```
"A: 0.2"
"B: 0.7"
"C: 0.9"
```

Comment: What code do you have so far? Show us what you have done.

Comment: No code per se yet, but my general idea is to iterate through the list, taking note of where the category changes. Then iterate once more to find the appropriate median value. It should work but it seems unnecessarily messy.

Comment: Is using a List for storage a hard requirement? Also, when you say "data is subject to change", does it mean that when another row is appended to the sorted list, your algorithm still needs to produce the correct result?

Comment: I am taking a generic csv file with the same headers, but different data, then applying my program to it. So therefore it should not be specific to one set of data. A new row is never created, as the list is only generated from the csv on input.

Comment: I say 300 rows, because at the moment that is the size i am dealing with. In the future it may be thousands or even more, though this shouldn't affect it adversely.

Comment: @LeffeBrune what do you think of my method? Is it overly complicated?

Comment: The problem will be easier to solve if you had a separate array/list for each category. I suggest you use a Map<String, List<RowObject>>. While reading a file keep adding rows to the entry in the map that corresponds to collection label of the row. Sort each list, get median by looking at middle (or two) element.

Comment: I think multiple passes will look messy, but no, your approach is not complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a single pass over a sorted list solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Medians {
  public static void printMedians(List<Row> rows) {
    if (rows.size() == 0) return;
    Collections.sort(rows);
    int currentCategoryIndex = 0;
    String currentCategory = rows.get(0).category;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
      if (i == rows.size() - 1
          || !currentCategory.equals(rows.get(i + 1).category)) {
        int categorySize = i + 1 - currentCategoryIndex;
        int medianIndex = currentCategoryIndex + categorySize / 2;
        double median;

        if (categorySize % 2 == 0) {
          median = rows.get(medianIndex - 1).stdDev < rows.get(medianIndex).stdDev
              ? rows.get(medianIndex - 1).value
              : rows.get(medianIndex).value;
        } else {
          median = rows.get(medianIndex).value;
        }

        System.out.printf("%s: %.1f%n", currentCategory, median);

        if (i < rows.size() - 1) {
          currentCategory = rows.get(i + 1).category;
          currentCategoryIndex = i + 1;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static class Row implements Comparable<Row> {
    private final String category;
    private final double value;
    private final double stdDev;

    public Row(String category, double value, double standardDeviation) {
      this.category = category;
      this.value = value;
      this.stdDev = standardDeviation;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Row o) {
      if (category.equals(o.category)) {
        return value == o.value ? 0 : value > o.value ? 1 : - 1;
      }
      return category.compareTo(o.category);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
    rows.add(new Row("A", 0.2, 0.05));
    rows.add(new Row("A", 1.3, 0.08));
    rows.add(new Row("A", 0.1, 0.1));

    rows.add(new Row("B", 0.6, 0.9));
    rows.add(new Row("B", 1.1, 0.6));
    rows.add(new Row("B", 0.7, 0.01));
    rows.add(new Row("B", 0.9, 0.05));
    rows.add(new Row("B", 0.1, 0.01));
    rows.add(new Row("B", 0.2, 0.08));

    rows.add(new Row("C", 0.5, 0.3));
    rows.add(new Row("C", 1.0, 0.14));
    rows.add(new Row("C", 2.1, 0.1));
    rows.add(new Row("C", 0.9, 0.04));
    printMedians(rows);
  }
}
```

But I like this one more:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class CategoryMedianCalculator {
  private final Map<String, List<Row>> categories = new HashMap<>();

  public void addRow(String category, double value, double stdDev) {
    List<Row> rows = categories.get(category);
    if (rows == null) {
      rows = new ArrayList<>();
      categories.put(category, rows);
    }
    rows.add(new Row(category, value, stdDev));
  }

  public Map<String, Double> getMedians() {
    Map<String, Double> result = new TreeMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Row>> entry: categories.entrySet()) {
      result.put(entry.getKey(), getMedian(entry.getValue()));
    }
    return result;
  }

  private static double getMedian(List<Row> rows) {
    Collections.sort(rows);
    int index = rows.size() / 2;
    if (rows.size() % 2 == 0) {
      return rows.get(index - 1).stdDev < rows.get(index).stdDev
          ? rows.get(index - 1).value
          : rows.get(index).value;
    } else {
      return rows.get(index).value;
    }
  }

  private static class Row implements Comparable<Row> {
    private final String category;
    private final double value;
    private final double stdDev;

    public Row(String category, double value, double stdDev) {
      this.category = category;
      this.value = value;
      this.stdDev = stdDev;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Row o) {
      return value == o.value ? 0 : value > o.value ? 1 : - 1;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CategoryMedianCalculator calc = new CategoryMedianCalculator();
    calc.addRow("A", 0.2, 0.05);
    calc.addRow("A", 1.3, 0.08);
    calc.addRow("A", 0.1, 0.1);

    calc.addRow("B", 0.6, 0.9);
    calc.addRow("B", 1.1, 0.6);
    calc.addRow("B", 0.7, 0.01);
    calc.addRow("B", 0.9, 0.05);
    calc.addRow("B", 0.1, 0.01);
    calc.addRow("B", 0.2, 0.08);

    calc.addRow("C", 0.5, 0.3);
    calc.addRow("C", 1.0, 0.14);
    calc.addRow("C", 2.1, 0.1);
    calc.addRow("C", 0.9, 0.04);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> median : calc.getMedians().entrySet()) {
      System.out.printf("%s: %.1f%n", median.getKey(), median.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```